# Dynamic "response-timeout" and "connect-timeout" per route in spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I am using spring cloud gateway for routing. I am using dynamic routing stored in the database by setting parameter
"exchange.getAttributes().put(ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR, mergedUrl);"

Dynamic routing works fine. I wanted to know just like dynamic routing is there a possibility of setting response timeout or connection timeout.

I looked at the code of the spring cloud gateway and found that these settings are stored in metadata of Route object which is an unmodifiable map. So we cannot set the value of these dynamically once the route is created.

Is there a way to set timeouts dynamically just like route URL?

> route application.yml

```
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:   
        - id: dynamicroute
          uri: no://op
          predicates:
          - Path= /**
          filters:
           - name: Filter1  
           - name: CustomRoutingFilter # This filter will route dynamically.
```